# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘T&’ to an rvalue of type ‘T’ t++ which std::atomic<T>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std, atomic

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

class T{
public:
    int i = 0;
    friend T operator++( T& t, int);
};

 T operator++( T& t, int){
        t.i++;
        return T(); // please ignore this. I only care for it to compile right now
    }



int main() {

    atomic<T> t;
    t++;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use atomic with a custom class B but im getting error:

```
*Compilation error #stdin compilation error #stdout 0s 4400KB
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:21:3: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘T&’ to an rvalue of type ‘T’
  t++;
   ^~
In file included from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/atomic:202:7: note:   after user-defined conversion: ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::operator _Tp() const [with _Tp = T]’
       operator _Tp() const noexcept
       ^~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:11:4: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘T operator++(T&, int)’
  T operator++( T& t, int){
    ^~~~~~~~*
```

I am using *friend* to avoid using explicit conversion

```
(T(t))++;
```

if I am defining the operator++ with const like this:

```
friend T operator++(const T& t, int);
```

it compiles but then of course its useless to me.

Comment: Is there a reason you use a non-member operator function?

Comment: I want to avoid  explicit converion (T(t))++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::atomic<T>::operator++` operators are only defined for integers and pointers (see the fine green print [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith)).

The compiler attempts to invoke `std::atomic<T>::operator T` to obtain a temporary copy of the contained `T` instance, and then call your own `operator ++` on it, which therefore requires a `const` reference parameter. `atomic` provides no way of locking, calling your own operator, and unlocking. Since this could lead to deadlocks (if your operator acquires some other lock), this would subvert `atomic`'s purpose anyways.

You probably need to use a lock like `std::mutex` explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `t++`, it is the same as [`(t.operator T())++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T), which is equivalent to [`(t.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load).

This returns a copy of the value held by the atomic, which is an rvalue. Incrementing an rvalue doesn't make sense (It is destroyed immediately), so perhaps you want to lock, load and then store?

Comment: so why does it work with int for example?
do we not get a copy of the int?

Comment: @skekTek Because with integral types and pointers, [`std::atomic<T>::operator++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) is used, which atomically increments the value (Using [`fetch_add`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add), which is also only for integral types and pointers). You could also consider making T a template class so you can have a non-atomic version with `int i` and an atomic version with `std::atomic<int> i`, which you could increment atomically.